# Constructing Regex for a simple string input

Tags: regex

I am a total Regex newbie. I am trying to write a regex for a string that will have a hyphen, followed by any number between 1 - 9, followed by any of {mo, w, h, m, d}. I came up with:

```
-[1-9]+(mo)?|[h|w|d|m]
```

That doesn't quite do what I want.

For ex: it matches -2wh which it shouldn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Newbie? If you're going to use regex, even for simple tasks, you need to learn basic regex syntax. See: [http://www.regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for some great tutorials to start off with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right.. just an small change:

-([1-9]+)(mo|[hwdm])

if you want to limit the string to have that (and nothing else) you must add:

^-([1-9]+)(mo|[hwdm])$

Also note that -10h is not going to work because you excluded the zero.. if you want to include it but not as first number is as easy as this:

^-([1-9][0-9]*)(mo|[hwdm])$

Comment: This works just right. I guess I was missing the anchors (to get an exact match) and for some reason I thought the OR operator (|) can only be used inside square brackets to indicate a set of acceptable values.

Comment: You're welcome. With Regex there's always something new you can learn.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
-[1-9]+(mo|[hwdm])
```

Comment: Sorry.. this matches -2wh and misses -22d. So I guess I have to retain that '+' next to [1-9]

Comment: @Dilip You talk about "followed by any number between 1 - 9" 22 isn't a number between 1-9. You should explain that you need a number between that range more time.

Answer (score 0):

This is corrected version of your regex that should work:

```
^-[1-9]+((mo)|[hwdm])?$
```

- You've forgotten `^` (begin of the string) and `$` (end of the string) signs. This is the reason, why your regex accepted `-2wh` string (which contains a valid `-2w` string which was matched)
- I've refactored your regex a little by replacing `(mo)?|[h|w|d|m]` with `((mo)|[hwdm])?`
- If you don't want to include strings containing only number (for example `-2`, `-8`), remove the `?` from this regex
- If you want to include any number (including zeros), replace `[1-9]+` by `[1-9][0-9]*`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to *anchor* the expression. It validates just fine, but there can be anything before and after what you're validating:

- `^` anchor means "start of line"
- `$` anchor means "end of line"

So validating your input against this should work:

```
^-[1-9](mo?)|[hwd]$
```

Note that within the brackets, you won't need a pipe (`|`) to separate characters. `[hwd]` is identical to `h|w|d`.

Comment: The author doesn't want to match a zero, so `\d` does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that does the trick, **plus** it doesn't capture unnecessary groups:

```
^-[1-9](?:mo|w|h|m|d)$
```

If you want to capture more digits between 1 and 9, use `[1-9]+`. If you just want to match digits, use `\d+`.

HTH